# aiogram. How to get the id of the message that has already been sent by the bot

Tags: python, bots, telegram, aiogram

The bot sends a message to the telegram channel, how to get the id of the same message from the chat, in order to send a reply to it, thus forming a comment?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send the message:

```
await message.answer("Hello")  # Or any way
```

You can just use variables:

```
msg = await message.answer("Hello")
print(msg)
print(msg["message_id"])  # to get only message id
```

Output:

```
{"message_id": 7134, "from": {"id": %ur bot id%, "is_bot": true, "first_name": "Test v1.0", "username": "test_Bot"}, "chat": {"id": %id of the chat%, "first_name": %users first name%, "last_name":  %users last name%, "username": %users username%, "type": "private"}, "date": 1657035057, "text": "Hello"}
7134
```